# Multiple page print using iText pdf in landscape orientation

Tags: android, printing, itext, pdf-generation

I have tried [itextPdf_page_orientation](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/page-events-itext5/page-orientation-and-rotation) but the problem is - only first page is proper rest all pages are printed in half area.
Here is an image which will help you understand the issue.
[image]

I have tried both setting the page size `PdfPage.A4.rotate()` and setting the event to PdfWritter.
Here is the code snipet.

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    final String PARENT_PATH = 
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/.GSTInvoice";
    Document document = null;
    try {
        File file = new File(PARENT_PATH);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        File pdfFile = new File(file, "last_sales_summary");

        document = new Document();
        document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
        event = new RotateEvent();

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(pdfFile));
        writer.setPageEvent(event);
        document.open();
        event.setOrientation(PdfPage.LANDSCAPE);
        taxList = new ArrayList<>();

        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();
        printPage(document, writer, cb);

        if (document != null && document.isOpen()) {
            document.close();
        }
        return pdfFile.getPath();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (document != null && document.isOpen()) {
            document.close();
        }
    }
    return null;
}


private void printPage(Document document, PdfWriter pdfWriter, PdfContentByte pdfContentByte) throws Exception{


    int noOfPages = getNoOfPages();
    BaseFont latoLight = BaseFont.createFont("assets/Lato-Light.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    Font light = new Font(latoLight, 8);
    for (int i=1;i<=noOfPages;i++) {
        if (i != 1) {

            document.newPage();
            pdfWriter.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
            event.setOrientation(PdfPage.LANDSCAPE);
            document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4.rotate());
        }

        addTopPart(document);

        addMiddleTable(document, i);

        if (noOfPages>1) {
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(new Phrase("Page " + i + "/" + noOfPages, light));
            paragraph.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            paragraph.setSpacingBefore(8f);
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(pdfContentByte, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
                    paragraph,
                    (document.right() - document.left()) / 2 + document.leftMargin(),
                    document.bottom() - 10, 0);
        }
        event.setOrientation(PdfPage.LANDSCAPE);
    }
}
```

Any input will be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried doing `event.setOrientation(PdfPage.LANDSCAPE)` before `document.open()`?

Comment: Yes, Its not working. I think the orientation is right, it's the page size or dimension which is causing this issue.

Comment: Please share the PDF in question.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Here is the [pdf file link](https://github.com/Siddharth-Dev/LandscapePrint/blob/master/sample_file.pdf). Also this the link of [project](https://github.com/Siddharth-Dev/LandscapePrint) in case you want to debug the issue.

Comment: The only peculiarity of the PDF is that the first page has a page rotation of 0 while the second one has a page rotation of 90. This is due to what I hinted at in my first comment: By doing `event.setOrientation(PdfPage.LANDSCAPE)` *after* `document.open()` the first page is not rotated by the event listener, only all following ones. Other than that all pages have a mediabox of a portrait A4 page with rotated, page-filling content. As you indicate that changing the order of `event.setOrientation` and `document.open` does not change the behavior, the print manager in question seems to be buggy.

Comment: You might try to remove all `event.setOrientation(PdfPage.LANDSCAPE)` calls; this should result in all pages to become like the first one. Or you might want to remove all that code setting and changing rotation and instead instantiate the `Document document` using `new Document(new RectangleReadOnly(842,595))`, i.e. without any rotation at all; as the print manager appears not to handle rotation properly, this might also result in a desired behavior.

Comment: Okay, I'll try this and let you know

Comment: @mkl Thanks man, your suggestion to use ```RectangleReadOnly(842,595)``` worked.

Comment: Ok. I'll turn my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only peculiarity of the PDF is that the first page has a page rotation of 0 while the second one has a page rotation of 90.

This is due to what I hinted at in my first comment: By doing `event.setOrientation(PdfPage.LANDSCAPE)` after `document.open()` the first page is not rotated by the event listener, only all following ones. Other than that all pages have a mediabox of a portrait A4 page with rotated, page-filling content.

As you indicate that changing the order of `event.setOrientation` and `document.open` does not change the behavior, the print manager in question seems to be buggy.

You might try to remove all `event.setOrientation(PdfPage.LANDSCAPE)` calls; this should result in all pages to become like the first one.

Or you might want to remove all that code setting and changing rotation and instead instantiate the Document document using `new Document(new RectangleReadOnly(842,595))`, i.e. without any rotation at all; as the print manager appears not to handle rotation properly, this might also result in a desired behavior.

As the OP reported in a comment,

> your suggestion to use `RectangleReadOnly(842,595)` worked.